# Disable prealloc in ext4

Tags: filesystems, ext4, pre-allocation

I need to disable `prealloc` feature in ext4. But there is not a mount feature called `disprealloc`. I would like to know if there are any methods to disable prealloc feature.

Any suggestions in this regard will be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by prealloc feature? discard/nodiscard seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: maybe not,discard/nodicard is feature associated with deleting file,most used in SSD write amplification.I have finished disable prealloc in ext4 code,It is not very difficult....I was scared before

Comment: There is no such thing as "prealloc" feature in ext4.   Can you say a bit more about what you think you are wanting to disable and why you want to disable it?

Comment: I have got a SMR/HA disk,but the random read/write is bad.So I want to change ext4 in linux-4.2.0 to fit in SMR/HA feature,and the ext4 of linux-4.2.0 is on basis of seagate smr_fs_ext4.I want to set write position in write pointer,so I want to disble prealloc feature and I really have done this.thanks a lot for your attention,now I think change ext4 to fit in SMR/HA disk is a lot of work and ext4 is not a smr/ha friendly filesystem, so I think maybe this is not very feasible.